# How to add param value to AppAssets Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I defined recaptcha key in $config params:

```
$config['params'] = [
    'recaptcha_private' => 'SECRET',
    'recaptcha_public' => 'NOT_SECRET'
];
```

How can I add this param to AppAssets?

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $cssOptions = ['rel'=>"stylesheet preload",'as'=>'style'];
    public $css = [
        /*SOME CSS*/
    ];
    public $js = [
        'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=HERE I NEED NOT_SECRET KEY'
    ];
    public $depends = [];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `init()` method in your asset bundle like this

```php
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $cssOptions = ['rel'=>"stylesheet preload",'as'=>'style'];
    public $css = [
        /*SOME CSS*/
    ];
    public $js = [
        'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=',
    ];
    public $depends = [];

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        $this->js[0] .= Yii::$app->params['recaptcha_public'];
    }
}
```

Don't forget to call `parent::init()` when overriding the init method of `AssetBundle`. But this approach might cause problems later because you have to be careful about appending the key when customizing asset bundles in config.

The safer variant might be using customization to set up js url with key from web.php config.

```php
return [
    // ...
    'components' => [
        'assetManager' => [
            'bundles' => [
                'app\assets\AppAset' => [ //modify to match your namespace
                    'js' => [                                          
                        'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```